# Converting recurrence relation to summation, trivial problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I am reading book concrete maths, in which at some point authors speak about general method of converting recurrence relation of type $a_n T_n = b_n T_{n-1} + c_n$ .

Then one multiplies the above relations with $s_n$ called summation factor.

which makes the equation : $s_n a_n T_n = s_n b_n T_{n-1} + s_n c_n$

The factor $s_n$ is chosen to make : $s_n b_n =  s_{n-1} a_{n-1}$

....

What I didn't get in all this is: The relation $s_n =  s_{n-1} a_{n-1} / b_n $ gets expanded to :

$$ s_n = a_{n-1} a_{n-2} ... a_1 / b_n b_{n-1}...b_2 $$

How did above step happened I am wondering , why $b_n$ starts with $b_2\ to\ b_n $ in divisor? . Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$s_n=\frac{a_{n-1}}{b_n}s_{n-1}=\frac{a_{n-1}a_{\color{red}{n-2}}}{b_nb_{\color{blue}{n-1}}}s_{\color{red}{n-2}}=\cdots=\frac{a_{n-1}a_{n-2}\cdots a_\color{red}{1}}{b_nb_{n-1}\cdots b_\color{blue}{2}}s_{\color{red}{1}}$$

Comment: Now is the perfect time for me to feel idiot! :) . Thanks

Comment: Here is an awfully crowded club, I can tell you...

Comment: one more thing, suppose $a_n = 1$ and $b_n = 2$ , what should I take value of $a_0$ and $b_0$ and $s_0$ , I am little confused yet. thanks

Comment: It all depends the range of $n$ for which the identity $a_nT_n=b_nT_{n-1}+c_n$. If this holds for every $n\geqslant1$, you may choose any (nonzero) $a_0$ you like, for example $a_0=1$ and any (nonzero) $s_0$ you like, for example $s_0=1$, and set $s_1=1/b_1$, then $s_n=a_n\cdots a_1/(b_n\cdots b_1)$. Or any constant multiple of this.